# unable to apply sort order in solr

Tags: solrnet

hi Please tell me how to apply multiple valued sort order in solr here is my code given below,
I am using solr net for this.

```
private QueryOptions ConstructQueryOperation(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        QueryOptions queryOption =new QueryOptions();

        queryOption.Rows = searchCriteria.Pagination.PageSize;

        queryOption.Start = ((searchCriteria.Pagination.CurrentPage+1) - 1) * searchCriteria.Pagination.PageSize;

        if (searchCriteria.SortCriteria != null)
        {
            foreach (var sortItem in searchCriteria.SortCriteria)
            {
                if (sortItem.Value.ToString() == ListSorter.SortingOrder.Descending.ToString())
                {
                    queryOption.AddOrder(new SolrNet.SortOrder(sortItem.Key, Order.DESC));
                }
                else
                {
                    queryOption.AddOrder(new SolrNet.SortOrder(sortItem.Key, Order.ASC));
                }
            }

        }
        return queryOption;

    }
```

I am getting a bad server request.
Can anyone let me know what needs to be done exactly.

Comment: You need to the check the Solr log to see the exact error. It could be a field name mismatch.

Comment: i am able to sort using the following query    queryOption.OrderBy =new[] {new SortOrder("CreatedDt", Order.DESC),new SortOrder("State",Order.DESC)}; there is some syntax error i guess

Comment: @Mauricio you where right i had mentioned wrong field name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a field name mismatch. .Net code was referring to a field that didn't exist in the Solr schema.